# SQLITE: Calculate price changes with multiple rows in same table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a database with the following schema and I need to be able to calculate the difference when a price changes for any given store and include it in the query results. Is it possible with the following query?:

```
SELECT * from prices
WHERE rowid in (
    SELECT p.rowid from prices p 
    LEFT JOIN prices p1 
    ON (p1.rowid = (select max(rowid) from prices pp  where pp.rowid < p.rowid)) 
    WHERE p.price > p1.price + .01 and p.address = p1.address  
)
```

I would like to print a report that looks similar to this:

### Store--------State-------City--------Address-------Price-------Difference

ACME........Ohio........Akron........123 Elm.......10.25......+0.25
ACME........Ohio........Akron........123 hurst.....9.25.......+1.25
ACME........Ohio........Akron........125 Elm.......5.00.......-0.60

Here is a sample of the data that I am working with:
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/d020f/37/0

Comment: Dit you notice that `ROWID`  are not guaranteed to be monotonicly increasing, for example if rows are deleted or if they are specified on input ?

Comment: Would that matter if a match is based on "p.address = p1.address "?

Comment: Fine, but what means `p1.rowid =(select max(rowid)... ` if rowids are not monotonic ? As a general rule, you should avoid < or > on rowids.

Comment: What is the problem you are having with this query?

Comment: I need to be able to calculate the difference when a price changes for any given store and include it in the query results.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the change between a price and the one before it you could do that using the insert query. Below I set the price to be 3.64 . In the query I've ordered by row but it would be better to order by date

```
 INSERT INTO PRICES    
 Select  url, state, city, location, 3.64 as price, company, address, '5:45:11 PM 5/30/2014 est.', 3.64 -price as change FROM PRICES
 WHERE address = '1670 US-31 N & I-65'
 ORDER BY rowid DESC LIMIT 0,1
```

Comment: Still trying to figure out a solution, but thanks for trying to help.

Comment: is it the difference between the current price and any previous price?

Comment: So very close. In other words, the store with the highest price is 3.60. The difference in price per store is being calculated on that number when it should be just the store's previous price as you can see here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/107fc/20/0

Comment: could you give an example of the output you would like

Comment: Here ya go. Let me know if you have any other questions. And thank you again!

Comment: Yes in a way it did, but like I mentioned, it calculated the change (s1) based on the last store which was the highest at 3.60. For example, if a store's price before the increase was 3.45, and the new price is 3.50, it did NOT say the change was .05 but rather .15... I hope you understand what I am trying to say.

Comment: I meant the one with the insert statement

Comment: No. I am trying to use this as a view, but I can rely on php to do some calculations if needed.

Comment: it would be easier to use php for some calculations. I think it's possible to get the results with sqlite but it wouldn't be very efficient